# Office AddIn Events when document open

Tags: office-js

I am developing with Office Web AddIn with dialog function.

Is there any event when opening word document before clicking `ExecuteFunction`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Normally you'd open the add-in after the document is loaded / are you using auto-open functionality?

Comment: @MaviDomates I am using `Custom buttons and menu commands` instead of `Task panes`, for `Task panes`, it will open directly after we open the document, but for `buttons`, it will only fire when we click the button in the ribbon. I need any event which will fire when we open the document and before we click the ribbon button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can now answer after further clarification in the comments.

The developer is using the [functionFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/functionfile) capability. This results in ribbon buttons just configured to execute a global JS function.

*"I need any event which will fire when we open the document and before we click the ribbon button"*

This is not possible. For Office add-ins to work, they must be active and in context. For the functions, they only come in play once you click to the button (so the client makes a call and loads the pointed HTML / or endpoint in a headless or internal browser). What you want to do can't be achieved with functions. The best you can achieve is to auto-load the taskpane.